PI System Explorer attribute created from Analyses: Pi point cannot be found
I am using pi system explorer to create tags in the analyses tab using math that references already existing tags. At the end of the calculation code I write I map it to attributes but while it works for some points, for others it tells me that the pi point cannot be found, even though I just made it and checked it in. I tried remaking it and refreshing and some of the fix themselves but others haven't. What should I do other than this that might fix my issue? When I evaluate my analyses they all work just fine, but the attribute part is getting really frusterating.
